# how to upload gif images in swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, gif

I'm implementing an iOS app that uploads images to a web server. The app provides an extension that allows upload from apps like Twitter, Messages, etc.

When the image is selected by the user, it may be presented by the `itemProvider` either as an `UIImage`, `Data`, or `URL`. To deal with that, I create an `UIImage` object from what the `itemProvider` provides and send this new `UIImage` object to the upload function.

This latter (the upload function) uses Alamofire to upload the image and thus, requires to have a `Data` object, which I obtain by using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` of the `UIImage` object. That works for most images but in the case of `gif`, it does not. The .gif loses its animation property and only a static image is uploaded.

So my question is how to have a `Data` object from the `UIImage` object which preserves the .gif properties (animation) of the original file?

Thank you very much for the help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it, pretty simple.

```
myData = Data(contentsOf: url)
```

But XCode requires to catch error which gives:

```
do{
   try myData = Data(contentsOf: url)
}catch let error{
   print ("Error \(error)")
}
```